# Postgresql rds: relation .... does not exists

Tags: postgresql

This seems to be a question that is asked alot all of the answers that I have read do not seem to pertain to this situation.  I maybe wrong, I am a newbie but here is the question.

I am using  psl 11 in amazon rds.  I have one db on the instance with 2 schemas.  It is running slow in testing so I was going to run the  missing index query

```
SELECT   relname
    ,seq_scan - idx_scan AS too_much_seq
    ,CASE
        WHEN
          seq_scan - coalesce(idx_scan, 0) > 0
        THEN
          'Missing Index?'
        ELSE
          'OK'
      END
     ,pg_relation_size(relname::regclass) AS rel_size, seq_scan, idx_scan
```

FROM    pg_stat_all_tables
WHERE   schemaname IN( 'schemaname')
AND pg_relation_size(relname::regclass) > 80000
ORDER BY  too_much_seq DESC;

When I run it in this new environment I am getting a relation does not exists.

I have checked permissions, ownership, lowercase, I can see the table, run queries against the table, however I can't seem to get this query to work.  If I do a SELECT * from pg_stat_all_tables  I can see all of the tables that do not exists in he other query.

I am not sure what is wrong. I am pretty sure it is in the   pg_relation_size(relname::regclass)  section, I think that is where it is not finding the relation,  however I have been unable to find documentation on this function that would appear to shed light on my issue.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Why use the convolution `relname::regclass` when the `relid` is directly available in the table?

Comment: What is the full error message?  That is, what relation does it say does not exist?

Comment: because being a silly newbie, I just used the query I was provided and didnt know about the relid.  all of the google searches I came up will all showed the relname :(

Answer (score 1):

jjanes answered the question in his comment.

Why use the convolution relname::regclass when the relid is directly available in the table?

using the relid  fixed the issue